# Does HTTPOnly flag apply to persistent cookies

Tags: persistent, httponly

I understand HTTPOnly flag applies to session cookies. Does it apply to persistent cookies? Is anyone able to provide a reference? I have checked http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6265.txt on HTTPOnly flag but it is not explicitly stated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from [HTTP Cookies Explained](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/05/05/http-cookies-explained/):

> The expiration date on this cookie hasn’t changed, since the
>   identifying characteristics of the cookie are the same. In fact, the
>   expiration date won’t change until you manually change it again. That
>   means a session cookie can become a persistent cookie (one that lasts
>   multiple sessions) within the same session but the opposite isn’t
>   true. In order to change a persistent cookie to a session cookie, you
>   must delete the persistent cookie by setting its expiration date to a
>   time in the past and then create a session cookie with the same name.
>
> Keep in mind that the expiration date is checked against the system
>   time on the computer that is running the browser. There is no way to
>   verify that the system time is in sync with the server time and so
>   errors may occur when there is a discrepancy between the system time
>   and the server time.

further down:

> To create an HTTP-only cookie, just add an HttpOnly flag to your
>   cookie:

In the [Opera Dragonfly documentation](http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/documentation/storage/):

> HTTPOnly cookie Session and persistent cookies can also be HTTPOnly. A
>   HTTPOnly cookie can not be accessed by client-side scripting, which is
>   designed to help against cross-site scripting attacks. HTTPOnly
>   cookies are labelled with a tick icon in the HTTPOnly column.

it looks like you can also apply the HTTPOnly flag at least for Opera Dragonfly